# How to use the UART functionality in this Bluetooth module?

Tags: rf, uart, bluetooth

I'm using a Bluetooth module called SPBTLE-1S whose datasheet is here -
https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/spbtle-1s.pdf

In the datasheet, it says that I can use the UART functionality by setting the 'mode' to 001.[image]
But I've searched everywhere and could not find how to set the 'mode'. I want to know how I can use the UART functionality by setting the 'mode' to 001. How can I do this?

EDIT - Also, I don't seem to find information on how to put it to low power modes. How can I do that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this device is provided without stack, it only has a serial bootloader pre-programmed.

It means you have to programme it yourself (and thus select the functionality of the pins).

[There is the stack and software tools to do so.](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/evaluation-tool-software/stsw-bluenrg1-dk.html)